# docker: Converting docker command into docker-compose syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose

```
docker run --rm -it --name foo -h foo --net net1 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
docker run --rm -it --name bar -h bar --net net1 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

I wanted to ask how do I rewrite the command above in the docker-compose syntax?

Comment: You can't. `docker-compose` doesn't allow you to get into bash directly. You will need to use some other command and then you will need to use `docker-compose exec` to get into bash

Comment: well I am more interested in the --name part and the --net part. As I understand net is not required as they will sit in one network by default. But how do I specify --name so I can cross-refer items from containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `docker-compose` will create new **bridge** docker network for your setup. But if you have configured you docker network by yourself, you can specify it in your compose file, marking it as `external` network.

```
version: 3
services:
  foo:
    container_name: foo
    image: ubuntu:latest
    hostname: foo
    networks:
      - my_net

  bar:
    container_name: bar
    image: ubuntu:latest
    hostname: bar
    networks:
      - my_net

networks:  
 my_net:
   external:
   name: my_net
```

Answer (score 1):

For

```
docker run --rm -it --name foo -h foo --net net1 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
docker run --rm -it --name bar -h bar --net net1 ubuntu:latest /bin/bash
```

You will need to use something like below

```
version: 3
services:
  foo:
    image: ubuntu
    hostname: foo
  bar:
    image: ubuntu
    hostname: bar
```